# Saving an array to file in C++

Tags: c++

I have a custom class called Array. It stores the array of type T and a size integer.

Does this look right saving an array to file?

```
fout.write((char *)m_array, sizeof(T) * m_size);
```

How I'm storing it:

```
    bool save(const std::string &filename)
    {
        std::ofstream fout;

        // Open the file.
        fout.open(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

        // Validate that the file is open.
        if (!fout.is_open())
            return false;

        // Write the size to file.
        fout << m_size << std::endl;  

        fout.write((char *)m_array, sizeof(T) * m_size);

        fout.close();

        return true;
    }
```

Load function:

```
    bool load(const std::string &filename)
    {
        std::ifstream fin;
        int size = 0;

        // Open the file.
        fin.open(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

        // Validate that the file is open.
        if (!fin.is_open())
            return false;

        // Read the size from file.
        fin >> size;

        // Resize if needed
        if (size != m_size)
            resize(size); 

        fin.read((char *)m_array, sizeof(T) * m_size);

        fin.close();

        return true;
    }
```

The main file:

```
Array<int> a(10);

a.clear(); // set all values to 0. 

a[5] = 3; 

if (a.save("test.dat"))
    con.writeLine("Saved");
```

This gives the output values 0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0.

But on retrieval, using this:

```
fin.read((char *)m_array, sizeof(T) * m_size);
```

I'm getting 10,0,0,0,0,768,0,0,0,0.

What am I doing wrong? The second parameter says it wants the count, which would be sizeof(T) * m_size to me.

Update:
The alternative is this on saving:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
fout << m_array[i] << std::endl;
```

But I prefer the first method.

Comment: Add `fin.get();` after `fin >> size`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing formatted and unformatted writes to the stream. Rather than:

```
fout << m_size << std::endl;
```

You need to do:

```
fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&m_size), sizeof(m_size));
```

**EDIT:**
After seeing you're update you'll need to read, not with this:

```
fin >> size;
```

But with this:

```
fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&m_size), sizeof(m_size));
```

---

So it should be mentioned here that you're reinventing the wheel. As long as you're OK with this... None the less I think it's appropriate here for me to suggest using `vector<T>`. It would make your code more readable, less error prone, and potentially faster.

Given `vector<int> a` you can write to `ofstream fout` like this:

```
const auto a_size = size(a);

fout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a_size), sizeof(a_size));
fout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data(a)), sizeof(decltype(a)::value_type) * a_size);
```

Given `ifstream fin`, you can read like this:

```
size_t a_size;

fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a_size), sizeof(a_size));
a.resize(a_size);
fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data(a)), sizeof(decltype(a)::value_type) * a_size);
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0737289804b595a)

Comment: I'm getting ten -842150451's on retrieval using this. When reading in the size, do I need to do the same reinterpret_cast?

Comment: Adding this for both reading and writing gives me the correct result.

Comment: You can't read directly into `m_size`. If the `Array` was a different size, bad will happen because you won't know if you need to resize it. You'll still need to read into the temporary `size`.

Comment: Yes, I have this, and optional for the poster to include a temp local size instead of using the member variable. Thanks for the answer, @JonathanMee.

Comment: @user4581301 As long as he reads it in and then immediately uses it to resize his container that's fine.